# Google Analytics events regular expression grouping

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We have set-up JW Player (an off the shelf embedded video player) to send our video play events into Google Analytics as Events (they appear in `Behaviours > Events > Top Events > JW Video Plays`).  We stream from AWS Cloudfront with signed URLs so the URLs for each video play are computed and unique - something like this:

> rtmp://streaming.oursite.com/cfx/st/mp4:xtra/tutorial/video/somevideo.mp4?Key-Pair-Id=APKAJPGHQNAH3663VQQQ&Signature=m6HTuv-IRaR5N3zu58w1Rh5mIuhhETPuEVBMBQv9Tb1ZXvsy3lg9dgpp-FtBPwZYWkI5fR0kAuBir6OnAXst3F6FyXve7s5gQSdoJMtCDcGIFtyyw8kZCBaFPa71jr1sDy9L~xf3VDDH0tIksfXZ-z9t~tZg7tnfw~iVLfKDTtE_&Expires=1413316048

So in order to judge popularity we'd like to group the play events by their basic video path, e.g.

```
rtmp://streaming.oursite.com/cfx/st/mp4:xtra/tutorial/video/somevideo.mp4
```

I tried using the configurable JWPlayer id_string but that doesn't seem to work, so I am falling back to using regex in Google Analytics, but we can't seem to get the URL grouping to work.  We tried this advanced regex filter:

```
  ^(.*?)\?.*$
```

based on https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en which says

> ()  remember contents of parenthesis as item

but that has no effect.

Is it even possible, and if so what Regex should we be using please?

Comment: Have you tried testing in the https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?  might be easer to find the right match

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the first ? question mark, in (.*?). You've used it in the usual regex way to change greedy to non-greedy, as done in PHP/Java/Perl etc. But there appears to be nothing in the Google Analytics help screens to suggest it can rise to those heights. They only say it means 0 or 1 in their regex system.

So you need an alternative form for your regex. You could try just putting `^(.*)\?.*$` instead, but it probably won't work (however I couldn't see in the documentation whether GA is by default greedy or lazy, so it's worth trying first).

Failing that, then the alternative way to achieve what you want will be to use a character class in square brackets to look for all the possible letters and digits that could occur in your file names:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9/:.]*)\?.*$
```

(check if there are any other characters from your file names that should be in there as well).

Comment: Great answer - the ^(.*)\?.*$ didn't do it and I adapted you other idea to ^([a-zA-Z0-9/:.-_]*)\?.*$ but that still didn't do it.  Weirdly the so called "grouping" capability never kicks in...  it just ignores the apparently valid regex expression and lists out all the events...  Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case, take a look at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en. I don't know enough about GA to know if this will help, but the example it gives looks very close to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Many thanks Guy - I see how that would probably do it, but its a global fix at the event level, so I think I should look into other ways of cleaning the data we send into analytics using custom JS.